# Convert from Unix Epoch time (in microseconds) to DateTime in R

Tags: r

I have dates formatted like so: `1.475534e+15`, which when converted via https://www.epochconverter.com/ convert to `Monday, October 3, 2016 10:33:20 PM`

However, I cannot replicate this in R.

For example:

```
library(anytime)
anytime(1.475534e+15)
```

Yields `"46759781-01-30 14:33:20 EST"`

The same is true if I do something like

`as.POSIXct(1.475534e+15  / 1000,  origin="1970-01-01")`

The epochconverter site suggests that the time is in microseconds, but I haven't figured out how to convert from microseconds to a human-readable date.

Comment: You were close by using `anytime`; you "just" need to scale by 1e-6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- 1.475534e+15
as.POSIXct(a/1000000, origin="1970-01-01")
#[1] "2016-10-03 15:33:20 PDT"    # interpreted in my local tz
```

With 7 significant digits in the scientific notation, that gets us around 20 minutes of time resolution. If you need more than that, you'll need to get the data in different format upstream.